# Double complex matrix derived type in Fortran

Tags: matrix, fortran

I am new in fortran, and i want to write a double complex matrix derived TYPE that includes the Matrix elements. What i need to do is to define the type and initialize the matrix, define a routine that writes on file the Matrix TYPE in a readable form, and then to print this matrix on my screen. I tried with this program, which should assign the value 1d0 to every element of the matrix I don't know what is wrong, but it does not work. Can anybody help me?

This is my program

```
module matrices
   type matrix
      double complex, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: aa
   end type

    contains
   function assign(var)
      type(matrix) :: var
         integer*4 ii, jj
        do ii = 1, 2
     print *, ii
             do jj = 1, 3
        var%aa(ii, jj) = var%aa
     end do
         end do
   end function
end module matrices

program test
   use matrices
   type(matrix) :: AA
   AA = matrix(2d0)
   integer :: kk, ll
   do kk = 1, 2
      do ll = 1, 3
         write (*, *) AA(kk, ll)
      end do
   end do

end program test
```

Comment: What means "it doesn't work"? Avoid this phrase in good question.

Comment: i get following errors:                                                              var%aa(ii,jj)=var%aa                                      
           1
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 2 in assignment at (1)            
use matrices                                                   
            1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'matrices.mod' for reading at (1)

Comment: If it is allocatable, where do you `ALLOCATE(var(2,3))` ?

Comment: Also if `AA` is `type(matrix)` then `AA%aa = 2d0` should initialize the values, not `AA = matrix(2d0)`

Comment: I thought that you get the allocation when you define the values that i want to assign to the matrix. Am I thinking wrong? Should I first allocate, and then assign the value? In this case should I simply define the matrix as: double complex, dimension(2,3) :: a ??

Comment: Nope, see http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/allocated

Comment: I tried, but i get always the same errors. But the way to define the matrix that i told to you is explained here https://web.stanford.edu/class/me200c/tutorial_90/07_arrays.html

Comment: Is `aa` always `aa(2,3)` size, or does it vary?

Comment: In this program I don't need to modify it! So if i define aa as a 2x3 matrix it will be so for the whole program execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an up to date compiler you can simply write

```
type(matrix) :: AA
AA = matrix(arr)
```

provided that `arr` is, when the statement using it is processed, a rank-2 array of complex values.  In the code shown `2d0` is not a rank-2 array of complex values so it's no wonder the compiler barfs on the expression.  The up to date compiler is necessary because this automatic allocation is a recent feature of the language.

Of course, as things stand the compiler never gets to barf there, it refuses to compile the module `matrices`.  I suspect that it finds this statement

```
var%aa(ii, jj) = var%aa
```

most offensive, assigning an array (on the rhs) to one element of the same array (on the lhs).  That's probably never going to work. I can't figure out what that function is for, I'd delete it and get the rest of the code working.  One thing it is certainly not necessary for, and doesn't do properly, is to allocate the complex array and set values for it. I see it's not used elsewhere in the code.

Returning to the automatic allocation of the complex array component of `AA`, this statement

```
AA = matrix(arr)
```

does require that `arr` be a rank-2 array of (double) complex values.  For brevity and denseness you could simply write

```
AA = matrix(reshape([((2d0,1d0),ix=1,6)],[2,3]))
```

which will, if I have my syntax correct, assign the complex value `(2d0,1d0)` to every element of a `2x3` array.

Oh, and while I'm writing, a gratuitous comment: `double complex` is so last century.  Don't learn bad old ways, a much better approach would be

```
use iso_fortran_env

complex(real64), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: aa
```

The standard module `iso_fortran_env` defines, *inter alia*, standard constants for declaring 64-bit real numbers or, as here, complex numbers comprising 64-bit real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was helpful, but there are two problems left: I get this message when i use iso_fortran_env "Error: Can't open module file 'iso_fortran_nv.mod' for reading at (1)". Second is that, when i try to print the matrix, i get following message: "Syntax error in WRITE statement at (1)". Could you help me further? I know that I'm completely bad at using  fortran, but it is my first time.

Comment: BTW, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Sorry for being late. I'm using gfortran!

Comment: re OP's comment: *Can't open module file 'iso_fortran_nv.mod'* read my code (and your code) carefully, compilers are very precise in their requirements.  As for the *Syntax error in WRITE statement* - what `write` statement ?  For further Q&A ask another question, let's not continue this in comments, let's not continue in chat.